# Check if Windows credentials have sysadmin privileges for each SQL Server in list

Tags: sql-server, powershell, system-administration

I need to write a script [in anything, assumed powershell would be best] that checks to see if the given Windows or SQL Server credentials have sysadmin rights for each server in a list. I would like to loop through list pf SQL Servers within my environment and produce a log that tells me which servers I have sysadmin privileges for.

Comment: SO is not a script writing service, what have you tried already?

Comment: Along with the problem you should **include the code you have up until this point** (*make some effort to answer your problem/question as [so] is not a code writing service*). After [doing more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[mcve]**. I suggest reading [*How do I ask a Good Question*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*Writing the Perfect Question*](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour].

Comment: Please provide an example what you have attempted and where you need assistance. [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Most members on SO will help you as long as you put in the effort.

Comment: @techguy1029 I havent started yet, I need more of a high-level direction. My problem is i need to automate the checking of sysadmin privilege rights for a list of sql servers

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is [IS_SRVROLEMEMBER.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/is-srvrolemember-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```
IS_SRVROLEMEMBER ( 'role' [ , 'login' ] )
```

**Arguments**

' role '
Is the name of the server role that is being checked. role is sysname.

Valid values for role are user-defined server roles, and the following fixed server roles:

sysadmin    serveradmin
dbcreator   setupadmin
bulkadmin   securityadmin
diskadmin

' login '
Is the name of the SQL Server login to check. login is sysname, with a default of NULL. If no value is specified, the result is based on the current Execution context. If the parameter contains the word NULL will return NULL.

**| Return value | Description |**

0   login is not a member of role.

1   login is a member of role

NULL role or login is not valid, or you do not have permission to view the role membership.